# Struct and segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I am literally having a problem in debugging the actual cause of the **segfault**. The program is to gather a student's info. The menu driven is used to select a list of possible options such as 1 to add student, 2 to show hidden file's contents and 3 to display information.

Assume that once adding the information, I would like to display/read it. However, I cannot update/display information as segmentation fault appears and then terminates the entire program. Example is shown in the following.

> Please enter the following choice
>
> 1: Add Information
> 2: Update Information
> 3: Display Information
> 0: Exit
>
> Enter a number: 2
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Edit: I have been highly recommended to debug using gdb. Here is the result:

/gdb-test

```
Please enter the following choice
```

---

```
    1: Add Information
    2: Update Information
    3: Display Information
    0: Exit
```

---

Enter a number: 3

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554ff5 in display (resident=0x0, file1=0x0, res=0x0)
    at maincode.c:130
130     *resident = fopen(file1, "r");
(gdb)
```

Below is the source code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

struct student {
    char registration[MAX_SIZE], location[MAX_SIZE], faculty[MAX_SIZE];
        int yearOfBirth, monthOfBirth, dayOfBirth, layerArch1, layerArch2, levelOfStudy, graduatingYear;    
};

int writeInfo(FILE **resident, FILE **transient, const char *file1, const char *file2, struct student *res, struct student *tra);
int readTransient(FILE **transient, const char *file2, struct student *tra);
int display(FILE **resident, const char *file1, struct student *res);

/********************************************************************************/

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *resident, *transient;

    struct student *res = (struct student *) malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    struct student *tra = (struct student *) malloc(sizeof(struct student));

    char file1[MAX_SIZE] = "resident.txt";
    char file2[MAX_SIZE] = "transient.txt";

    int choice = -1;

    while (choice !=0) {
        printf("\n\tPlease enter the following choice\n\n");
        printf("*****************************************************\n");
        printf("\t\t1: Add Information\n");
        printf("\t\t2: Read Information\n");
        printf("\t\t3: Display Information\n");
        printf("\t\t0: Exit\n");
        printf("*****************************************************\n");

        printf("\nEnter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice) {
            case 0:
                exit(1);
            case 1:
                writeInfo(&resident, &transient, file1, file2, res, tra);
                break;
            case 2: 
                readTransient(&transient, file2, tra);
                break;
            case 3: 
                display(&resident, file1, res);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Please enter either 1, 2 or 3! O for Exit\n\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int writeInfo(FILE **resident, FILE **transient, const char *file1, const char *file2, struct student *res, struct student *tra) {

        *resident = fopen(file1, "w");
        *transient = fopen(file2, "w"); 

        if (*resident == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nError open file\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (*transient == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nError open file\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Enter a registration number [7 digits]: ");
            scanf("%s", res->registration);

            printf("Enter location (location in currency, AUS CND SIN): ");
            scanf("%s", res->location);
            strcpy(tra->location, res->location);

            printf("Enter faculty (ENG BUS SCI MED): ");
            scanf("%s", res->faculty);
        strcpy(tra->faculty, res->faculty);

            printf("Enter birth of year (19XX 200X): ");
            scanf("%d", &res->yearOfBirth);

            printf("Enter birth of month (XX): ");
            scanf("%d", &res->monthOfBirth);
        tra->monthOfBirth = res->monthOfBirth;

            printf("Enter birth of date (XX): ");
            scanf("%d", &res->dayOfBirth);
        tra->dayOfBirth = res->dayOfBirth;

            printf("Enter level of study (1 -first, 2- second, 3- third, 4-fourth, 5 - other): ");
            scanf("%d", &res->levelOfStudy);
        tra->levelOfStudy = res->levelOfStudy;

            printf("Enter graduating year (XXXX): ");
            scanf("%d",&res->graduatingYear);
        tra->graduatingYear = res->graduatingYear;

            printf("Enter layer of Architecture 1 (0-sensing, 1-network, 2-smart(hidden), 3-devices): ");
            scanf("%d",&res->layerArch1);

            printf("Enter layer of Architecture 2 (0-sensing, 1-network, 2-smart(hidden), 3-devices): ");
            scanf("%d", &res->layerArch2);
        tra->layerArch2 = res->layerArch2;

        //write entire sturcture to Student file
        fwrite(&res, sizeof(struct student), 1, *resident);

        fwrite(&tra, sizeof(struct student), 1, *transient);

        fclose(*resident);
        fclose(*transient);
}

int display(FILE **resident, const char *file1, struct student *res) {
    memset(&res, 0, sizeof(struct student));
    *resident = fopen(file1, "r");

    if (*resident == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file!\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fread(&res, sizeof(struct student), 1, *resident)) {
        printf("%d%s%d%d%d%d%d%s%d%s%d%d\n\n", res->yearOfBirth, res->registration, res->monthOfBirth, res->dayOfBirth, res->layerArch1, res->layerArch2, res->levelOfStudy, res->location, res->graduatingYear, res->faculty, res->dayOfBirth, res->monthOfBirth);
    }

    fclose(*resident);
}

int readTransient(FILE **transient, const char *file2, struct student *tra) {
    memset(&tra, 0, sizeof(struct student));
    *transient = fopen(file2, "r");

    if (*transient == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file!\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fread(&tra, sizeof(struct student), 1, *transient)) {
        printf("%d%d%s%d%s%d%d\n\n", tra->layerArch2, tra->levelOfStudy, tra->location, tra->graduatingYear, tra->faculty, tra->dayOfBirth, tra->monthOfBirth);
    }

    fclose(*transient);
}
```

What is the actual problem? Could someone help clarify/modify?

Thank you. I highly appreciate your help and cooperation.

Comment: I'd recommend reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Specifically the part about using a debugger; `gdb`, for example, should tell you the exact line that is causing the segfault.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @0x5453I have done editing and doing the debug. But I am still a bit lost

Comment: @TobySpeight I have edited my question thread and shown the gdb debug (which line/part)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while(fread(&tra, sizeof(struct student), 1, *transient))
```

with

```
while(fread(tra, sizeof(struct student), 1, *transient))
```

Rationale:
The function *fread* needs a pointer, i.e. *the address of a memory block*, but you're passing *the address of a variable that contains a pointer*.

Modify the rest of the functions accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I already did that and when reading, the output is wrong

Comment: But did it solved the segfault? My answer just address the segfault problem.

Comment: it did not output a desired output. However, it did remove the segmentation problem.